# Custom Request Builder Apache

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need a custom request builder that will return an instance which implements `HttpEntityEnclosingRequest`. Previously i have used `RequestBuilder` that does not serve my purpose.

what i have done earlier,

```
public class SharePointRequestBuilder {
  //default mime type
  private static final String JSON_ODATA_VERBOSE_MIME_TYPE = "application/json;odata=verbose";

  private RequestBuilder delegate;

  private SharePointRequestBuilder(RequestBuilder delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public static final SharePointRequestBuilder get(String uri)
      throws URISyntaxException {
    return new SharePointRequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.get(new URI(uri)));
  }

  public static final SharePointRequestBuilder post(String uri)
      throws URISyntaxException {
    return new SharePointRequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.post(new URI(uri)));
  }

  public final SharePointRequestBuilder setEntity(String entity, ContentType contentType) {
    delegate.setEntity(new StringEntity(entity, contentType));
    return this;
  }

  public final SharePointRequestBuilder setEntity(String entity, Charset charset) {
    delegate.setEntity(new StringEntity(entity, charset));
    return this;
  }

  public final SharePointRequestBuilder setEntity(HttpEntity entity) {
    delegate.setEntity(entity);
    return this;
  }

  public final SharePointRequestBuilder setHeader(String name, String value) {
    delegate.setHeader(name, value);
    return this;
  }

  public final SharePointRequestBuilder setHeaders(List<Header> headers) {
    headers.forEach(p-> delegate.setHeader(p));
    return this;
  }

  public final SharePointRequestBuilder withDefaultMimeType() {
    setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, JSON_ODATA_VERBOSE_MIME_TYPE);
    setHeader(ACCEPT, JSON_ODATA_VERBOSE_MIME_TYPE);
    return this;
  }

  public final HttpUriRequest build() {
    return delegate.build();
  }
}
```

When i will invoke `build()` method, i would expect an instance which implements `HttpEntityEnclosingRequest`instead of `HttpUriRequest`. Is there any way to customize `build()` method?

Please help.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava i have edited.